# Is shutting down and restarting different from doing restart?

Tags: mac-appstore, software-update

A first-level Applecare rep recommended shutting down and then turning on my computer to deal with an issue.  Specifically, she told me to do select "Shut Down" from the Apple menu, wait 20 seconds, and then turn it back on, explaining this is different from selecting "Restart".

This surprised me, because I thought restart incorporated a full shutdown, followed by an auto-restart.   She said no, that the software shutdown executed when one selects "Restart" is not as complete as the software shutdown executed when one selects "Shut Down".  She further explained, colloquially, that the latter allows the system to more fully reset (and that to truly get a full reset, you additionally wait ~20 seconds before turning it back on).

Is what she is saying correct?

Independent of (but related to) this, my computer freezes unless I do a restart about once a week.  An Applecare engineer explain this is likely because of errors that can accumulate in non-ECC RAM, which a shutdown flushes out.  He said the rate at which they accumulate varies with usage.  For some reason my usage causes fairly rapid accumulation of these errors, which is why I have to reboot more frequently than most.  I have found that restart (as opposed to shutdown + restart) is sufficient for this, suggesting that the former is sufficient to flush RAM.   Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

The only difference is power is actually (mostly) removed from the components (logic board, PCIe bus, etc.)

The difference from back in the day, was called a [warm restart or a cold restart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reboot#Warm) .

Why the difference?

It depends on the issue.  If you're having a hardware issue like a track pad not responding or a GPU acting weird, you may be asked to shutdown and then restart, usually removing the power cord and waiting for a period of time in between.  If you're having an issue with a service, like your web server not working, a warm restart is sufficient.

So, from a software perspective, they are identical.  From a hardware perspective, the difference is power is actually removed and reapplied.

Now, usually cold (re)boots are done.

It's important to note that an SMC reset sits in between a warm and a cold boot.  When you reset the SMC, you are "resetting" the values the chip has accumulated back to factory defaults.  You're forcing the SMC to go back to when it was first initiated and needs to "relearn" everything power, temp and fan related with your Mac.  When you reset the SMC, you actually do a warm reset as well.

> ...my computer freezes unless I do a restart about once a week.

You have a hardware issue - it's not normal to need to continually reboot a Mac in this manner.

> She further explained...the latter allows the system to more fully reset...you additionally wait ~20 seconds before turning it back on).

To *truly* get a cold reboot/reset, you need to disconnect *all* power.  So depending on your Mac model, you'd need to disconnect the battery as well.

> An Applecare engineer explain this is likely because of errors that can accumulate in non-ECC RAM, which a shutdown flushes out.

This statement from the Apple engineer is incorrect.

non-ECC memory isn't "building up" a cache of errors that must be flushed out;  that's not how this works.  While non-ECC memory won't "fix" the corrupted data, corruption is actually very rare, especially in desktop computers.    The worst that will happen is a glitch or a hung app.  If you're having this all the time, you may have faulty memory.

Start by running [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) (Hold `D` while booting).

Comment: Also note that these days if you think it is a hardware problem a cold restart should include pulling the power cable and pressing the power button 2-3 times. That discharges the residual charge left in system board circuitry (usually capacitors...). Often called "discharging flea power" (not kidding) and it assures you that there is zero  voltage in the system and everything **IS** truly off.

Comment: Thanks for the trip down memory lane @SteveChambers - I totally forgot about flea power!

Comment: Let's please dispense with the snarky "Ummmm---No", shall we?  I'd like the discussion to be respectful and collegial.  Proceeding:  (1) "non-ECC memory isn't 'building up' a cache of errors that must be flushed out; that's not how this works." According to http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~bianca/papers/sigmetrics09.pdf , "Single-bit soft errors in the memory array can accumulate over time and turn into multi-bit errors." ....

Comment: ... (2) "The worst that will happen is a glitch or a hung app". According to that same article, "In systems using memory without support for error correction and detection, a memory error can lead to a machine crash"...at least in the server space.  I don't know the extent to which what's written in that article is applicable to my situation, but I would be interested to hear your comments.  Also, I tried the hardware test.  It said there were no issues.

Comment: You do realize that’s about DRAM and well over 10 years old?  So, how about finding updated, relevant sources and refraining from admonishing people because you chose to take it with a negative connotation.  Please note, you’re free to post an answer

Comment: I don't presume to have your expertise on memory; that's why I *asked* if the article were relevant. But what I do understand (better than you) is how people are supposed to treat each other, and that phrasing is known to be inherently snarky. And even if you didn't know this, cleary I don't like it, which should be reason enough to stop. That's what a good guy would do.  Instead, you play the same game as most who are called on poor behavior:  rather than accepting responsibility, you attempt to deflect by suggesting it's my issue for choosing to interpreting it negatively. Nice try, but no.

Comment: I'll specfically reference the Stack Exchange Conduct Guidelines:  "No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language."  I believe most would acknowledge "Ummmm.... No." is a subtle put down.  Why not simply instead keep it neutral and say "That's not correct?"

Comment: You finding issues to be offended about is something you need to deal with.  That “Ummmmm, no” is my response to Apple, not you because after **years** of listening to some of the utter BS they sling, you’d understand.    It is your issue, if you don’t like my writing style, cool.  Down vote.  But don’t try to categorize anyone as “good/bad” guy because now you’ve just devolved this to name calling.  I’m done debating this.

Comment: There is no subtle put down; I’m very direct. Everyone who knows me knows this.  Again, that’s not directed at you, but if you’re intent on being  a victim, I can’t help you.

Comment: So when I raised the issue (which I was careful to do politely), why didn't you just explain that the snark was directed at Apple (had you done that, this wouldn't have devolved), instead of writing a combative response in which you effectively said "hey dude, this is your problem"?  Which was of course making it personal, and was thus of course going to get a strong response from me.  "You choose the actions, you chooose the consequences."

Comment: Because you chose to **admonish** because you took issue with writing style.  You chose to admonish before understanding what was being said because your initial reaction was to internalize it.  I’m the first person to admit a mistake, but I don’t and won’t apologize for my writing style especially when confronted with a knee-jerk reaction.

Comment: Let me give you an example.. if I said “believing that is silly or stupid or idiotic” that would be a put down ranging from subtle to direct.  Using your own description, “snarkyness” is a tone of voice and used for effect.  There’s a massive difference there.  This was a tone of exasperation.

Comment: You yourself admitted it was a putdown.  As someone who doesn't know you, how was I supposed to know it was directed at Apple?  You're giving me a hard time for reacting to what you acknowledge was a put down, yet you yourself are so prickly that you couldn't handle someone saying "Let's please dispense with the snarky 'Ummmm---No', shall we? I'd like the discussion to be respectful and collegial."  There's clearly a double standard here.  Cleary using put-downs is risky, because people who don't know you don't know where they're directed.

Comment: I'll give you credit for hanging in with this discussion rather than "slamming down the phone".  I expect if we were talking in person none of this miscommunication would have happened -- the dangers of the internet.  Indeed, we might even like each other :).  I'm willing to go for a fresh start, and delete this entire exchange.  Or not, if you'd rather not.  Up to you.

Comment: Maybe.  Most people like me because they know exactly where they stand with me,  I will never BS anyone, nor insult them. I only attack ideas

Comment: Understood.  But I feel we need to be careful when attacking ideas because ideas are voiced by people.  For instance, when I teach, students often say things that are wrong, and it's my job to correct them.  But I'm careful not to say "that's idiotic" (even if the idea is idiotic).

Comment: I didn’t get to finiish, the last comment... Maybe.  Most people like me because they know exactly where they stand with me,  I will never BS anyone, nor insult them. I only attack ideas.  That said...  i never admitted to a put down.  Theres two ways to solve this... [edit] the answer and put in the reason “didn’t like snarkyness” or, ask.. “dude, did I do something that you need to be snarky with me?”  I wouldn’t have care about the first and I would have expanded on the exasperation  for the second.   And yeah, i do like people that hold their ground.

Comment: Done.   About the hardware: Another reason I don't think it's the hardware is that this has been going on for at least a few years, and Apple did a complete motherboard replacement a year ago, which had no effect on the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108772/discussion-between-allan-and-theorist).